# how to restore orientdb container from backup

Tags: orientdb, orientdb-2.1

I am running orientdb as docker container with mounts on host filesystem. I have the database mounted on host on `/opt/orientdb/databases` and will like to restore lets say database from another container on another host on a different container.

Do i just copy the path to the database `/opt/orientdb/database/<database-name>` from the host to the second host and restart the container?

If not then what is the best way to restore from backups WHEN running on docker containers?

OrientDB version 2.1.12

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can copy the database from host1 to host2 and run another container on host2.
Be sure to stop the container on host1, sync/copy the database, start the container on host2.

If you need to run the two instances at the same time, you can use replication:

http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Distributed-Configuration.html